# relationship between interface and abstract classes

Tags: oop, interface, abstract-class

Can an abstract class inherits from an interface class ?I want to design and implement a class diagram for public transportation system.So i have designed something like this.

1)Limo **extends** (Abstract)Taxi **extends** (***Interface***)Vehicle **&** (Abstract)public transportation

2)Subway **extends** (Abstract)public transportation

3)mid-buss **extends** (Abstract)Buss **extends** (Abstract)public 
transportation **&** (***Interface***)Vehicle

4)large-buss **extends** (Abstract)Buss **extends** (Abstract)public 
transportation **&** (***Interface***)Vehicle

So if i want to implement these classes i have to implement the structure of interface's method in the abstract class.what do you think? is it correct to design something like above ?

Comment: What language are we talking about?

Comment: @Fildor C# or java .

Comment: In both languages abstract classes can implement interfaces.

Comment: " i have to implement the structure of interface's method in the abstract class" - At least in Java you can relay the implementation of an interface that the abstract class implements to the concrete class.

Answer (score 1):

```
Can an abstract class inherits from an interface class ?
```

Yes for Java. The following examples use Java syntax.

1. Limo extends (Abstract)Taxi extends (Interface)Vehicle & (Abstract)public transportation

`public class Limo extends AbstractTaxi{...}`

`public abstract class AbstractTaxi extends AbstractPublicTransportation implements Vehicle{...}`

`public interface Vehicle{...}`

`public abstract class AbstractPublicTransportation{...}`

2. Subway extends (Abstract)public transportation

`public class Subway extends AbstractPublicTransportation{...}`

3. mid-buss extends (Abstract)Buss extends (Abstract)public transportation & (Interface)Vehicle

`public class MidBuss extends AbstractBuss{...}`

`public abstract class AbstractBuss extends AbstractPublicTransportation implements Vehicle {...}`

4. large-buss extends (Abstract)Buss extends (Abstract)public transportation & (Interface)Vehicle

`public class LargeBuss extends AbstractBuss{...}`

Note, that the AbstractTaxi doesn't seem useful yet, because there is only one subclass for that abstract class. However, it's not wrong to introduce additional abstractions to become extensible .